# Bottom Sheet vertical scroll not working

Tags: android, scroll

I have two recycler view inside bottomsheet, one is horizontal and other one is vertical.
I am able to scroll horizontally but not able to scroll vertically in second recycler view.
Is there any way to do vertical scroll?

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me use NestedScrollview in xml
Like that

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       >

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFeaturedLoc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    />


<ProgressBar
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/home_progress"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then set vertical scroll view in java file 
like that

```
 recyclerViewFeaturedLoc.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```